# javascript inherit Function context

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to inherit the function context without binding it.
Is that possible.

Look below

```js
const test = {
  prop: 42,
  func: function() {
    return this.prop;
  },
};
const fn = test.func;
console.log(fn()) // this show undefined;

console.log(test.func()) // this show 42;

console.log(fn.bind(test)()) // this show 42, I dont like it though;
```

Why dose not `fn` inherit the context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: `const fn = test.func.bind(test)` - In a naive way you can think of `this` being a secret argument passed to functions which is defined by the object before the dot. In `test.func()` the `this` is `test`. Whereas with `func()` the `this` is undefined or the window/global object.

Comment: It doesn't automatically "inherit" the context because that is how JavaScript works. I understand that `.bind()` is a little messy, but it really is the way to do it.

Comment: What you did is basically `cosnt fn = function() { return this.prop; }`. This function knows nothing about any other object, it just takes current context which is `window`

Comment: "_Why dose not fn inherit the context?_" Because JS obejcts don't have any "context" or "parent". Objects are freely allocated to the memory, and any object property or a variable can refer to an object (functions are also objects).